# Killing program using sigquit while using readline

Tags: linux, signals, libreadline

My C program is reading a line from standard input using libreadline. I have only one terminal. How do I kill my program using SIGQUIT? Pressing ctrl+\ is not working.

I have tried pressing ctrl+, ctrl+++. ctrl+backspace etc.

Comment: On Linux, `Ctrl+D` sends "EOF". On Windows it would be `Ctrl+Z`, IIRC.

Comment: Does your program have a signal handler for SIGQUIT?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to send a SIGQUIT signal to your C program that is reading input from the terminal using readline.
Open another terminal/shell instance - Then you can send the kill command from there without interrupting readline input:

```
kill -SIGQUIT <program_pid>
```

or
try `Ctrl + c` to kill the program